# OR with 3 arguments in java

Tags: java, bitwise-or

Why does this statement does not work

```
boolean b = (y==3-x)||(y==3)||(y=3+x);
```

but this one does

```
boolean b = (y==3-x)||(y==3);
        b = b || (y == x-3);
```

and `&&` statement has no problems with number of arguments passed

```
boolean b = x < 7 && x >= 0 && y < 7 && y >= 0;
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: What's not working with the first one? Could it be the `y=3+x` that should be `y==3+x`?

Comment: It does 'work'. It may not conform with your expectations, whatever they may be. It isn't the same thing. And without stating your expectations you haven't provided an answerable question.

Comment: hmm yes you are right, i should have mentioned i wanted to bitwise OR the 3 boolean arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the **first case**:

```
boolean b = (y==3-x)||(y==3)||(y=3+x);
```

You are doing the assignment not comparison for `(y=3+x)`

Change it to:

```
boolean b = (y==3-x)||(y==3)||(y==3+x);
```

and it will work for you

However in the **second case**:

```
boolean b = (y==3-x)||(y==3);
        b = b || (y == x-3);
```

You are doing the comparison everywhere thats why it is working for you!

Also in the third case you are doing comparison

```
boolean b = x < 7 && x >= 0 && y < 7 && y >= 0;
```

**NOTE:-**

**==** is for comparison and **=** is for assigment.

**<,>,<=,>=, ==** are all used for comparison

Comment: oops missed that 2nd = sign on the last one, seriously sometimes even the smallest bugs are difficult find.

Comment: @PratyushDhanuka:- Yes...and if my answer helped you then do accept it as an answer! :)

Comment: @PratyushDhanuka:- And yes even the best miss it ..so never mind! ;)

Answer (score 3):

You missed an equals sign, meaning the last parenthesis assigns `3+x`to `b`, evaluates to `int` rather than `boolean` and so can't be used for a logical OR expression. This works, though:

```
boolean b = (y==3-x)||(y==3)||(y==3+x);
```